# d3.js tag cloud: setting text size range

Tags: d3.js

A further question from [d3.js Tag Cloud size from a Json/array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692276/d3-js-tag-cloud-size-from-a-json-array)

```
var jWord = ["abc","def","ghi","jkl"];
var jCount = [2, 5, 3, 8];

  d3.layout.cloud().size([650, 140])
      .words(d3.zip(jWord, jCount).map(function(d) {
        return {text: d[0], size: d[1]};
      }))
      .rotate(function() { return 0; })
      //.rotate(function() { return ~~(Math.random() * 2) * 90; })
      .fontSize(function(d) { return d.size; })
      .on("end", draw)
      .start();
```

Now I use the original values of jCount as textsize. Assuming the jCount may vary, I'd like to set a size range (min 10px to 50px).

```
var maxCount = d3.max(jCount);
var s = d3.scale.linear().domain([10,50]),range([0, maxCount)]);
```

Then I changed

```
  .words(d3.zip(jWord, jCount).map(function(d) {
    return {text: d[0], size: s};
  }))
```

I changed "size:s" part into many other possibly guessed forms, but it doesn't work. I'm still getting familiar with d3.js/jquery/svg syntax, so for now i can't really figure it out how to set this. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s` is a function which maps domain to range. So change the line to

```
.words(d3.zip(jWord, jCount).map(function(d) {
  return {text: d[0], size: s(d[1]) };
}))
```

You also need to swap `.domain` and `.range` in the definition of `s` (and change the comma to a dot) -- `.domain` sets the input range and `.range` the output range.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Upon your advice: I changed var s = d3.scale.linear().domain([2, maxCount]).range([10,50]); Thanks for defining domain and range. :-)